# Pygments: use an unknown/unsupported language

Tags: jekyll, pygments

I would like to use pygments for basic line-numbering only for files like *krb.conf*, Asterisk's *extensions.conf* or *pam-configuration*.

I use pygments via Jekyll.

```
{% highlight WHATOPUTHERE lineos %}
CODE CODE
{% endhighlight%}
```

However, I need to specify some language (otherwise nothing is produced). The same for unknown languages.

Software:
* Jekyll 0.11.2
* Pygments 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [plain text](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.special.TextLexer) language that you can use for situations where nothing else fits. I've just tested with the latest github-pages gem (uses Jekyl 1.4.3 and Pygments 0.5).

```
{% highlight text linenos %}

require 'yaml'
require 'rubygems'
require 'stringex'

{% endhighlight %}
```